# Force Excel to recognize entry as text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am entering phone numbers in one column and the initial zero is being eliminated when I type enter for each cell.

I can only guess that this is because Excel is identifying it as a number rather than a text cell.

So how do I change the type of cell from a number to text so it does not delete the 0 at the beginning of the number. e.g. 0702 will be saved in the cell as 702.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options here:

1. Change cells' number formatting to "text" BEFORE entering data
2. Type `'` just before the numbers, it won't be displayed in the cells, but force Excel, but force it to consider entry as text.

Comment: can you put ' this before in cell in bulk? I have cell data with 60000 cells.

Comment: You need to first the cells as text,  or insert `'` BEFORE ENTERING YOUR DATA.  If your data is already entered,  then original formatting is lost. Do you have your data only in an Excel file or also somewhere else?